# Reference Dll not copying to bin even though copylocal is set to true

Tags: visual-studio-2012, msbuild

I have a project - projA to which I have added a reference for another project - projB which is located in the same solution.

One of the dll's in projB which has its CopyToLocal set to true. When I build the entire solution the dll is copied to the bin directory of projB but not to the bin directory of projA.

What needs to be set to get it to copy to the bin directory of projA.

Thank you,
gmat

Comment: VS 2012 , .net framework 4.5 solution

Comment: MSBuild uses reflection to discover a DLL like this.  If projB.dll does not actually contain an assembly reference to the DLL then it doesn't know that it needs to be copied.  Could happen if it uses Assembly.Load() or [DllImport] for example.  Or if the code in projB doesn't actually use the DLL at all.  Have a look-see with ildasm.exe, the manifest shows the dependencies.  Workaround is to copy it explicitly yourself with xcopy.exe in a post-build event.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Hans. The dll in question is Microsoft.Patterns.Unity. It is referenced in the assembly in projB. There are other Enterprise Library dll's referenced similarly including Microsoft.Patterns.Unity.Configuration and they all are copied over to projA's bin upon building the solution. All except Microsoft.Patterns.Unity

Comment: Well, clearly not putting that in your question was a drastically bad idea :(

Comment: sorry about that Hans. The dll used to get copied to the bin previously. I suspect something changed in the proj file but I cannot figure out what.